# Marginal mean is totally different from real mean! why?? how should I state difference between means?

Tags: anova, spss, mean, ancova, marginal-distribution

I ran pairwise comparison between three goups in terms of stress hormone after ANCOVA and I found hormone level in group 1 is higher than two and two is higher than three (68, 57, 44). In discussion section when I wanted to talk about how much the level of hormone in group 1 is higher than two other groups and state it as percentage I found that real means are not too different (64, 58, 57). Now, the problem is that how should I discuss about that? based on marginal means? or should I forget marginal means and simply mention difference between real means? in this situation, 58-57=1 is not too odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you discuss it in terms of adjusted means but be sure to also included the unadjusted means and the condition means on the covariate so the reader can see why the adjusted means differ more than do the unadjusted means. If you are using SPSS, what they call "estimated marginal means" are traditionally called "adjusted means."  SAS calls them "least squares means."

Comment: thanks for your answer. How should I include that in my result? should I simply put that in a bracket next to adjusted means?

Comment: You could have a table showing all means. I don't think there is any one standard way of reporting those results.